# Removing ggplot2 legend removes whole data from the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here I have 2-dim numeric array `dataset` and numeric 1-dim array of labels `clustring`. Then I plot it with the following code:

```
  s = data.frame(x = dataset[,1], y = dataset[,2])
  p = ggplot(s, aes(x, y))
  p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(clustering)))
```

which displays beautiful picture: [image: plot]

Now I want to remove legend completely, so [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/) I've found possible solution:

```
# Remove legend for a particular aesthetic (fill)
p + guides(fill=FALSE)

# It can also be done when specifying the scale
p + scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE)

# This removes all legends
p + theme(legend.position="none")
```

but none of such commands wont help. It shows empty plot instead: [image: empty plot]

So how do I remove the legend from my plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

s = data.frame(x = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20), clustering = rep(c(1, 2), 10))

p <- ggplot(s, aes(x, y))+
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(clustering)))+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position="none")
p
```

In your code, you are not saving the plot again after each time you add something to it. You can fix this by changing the lines that add to the plot:

```
# Remove legend for a particular aesthetic (fill)
p = p + guides(fill=FALSE)
```

But the way I wrote is is more common R formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Use `show.legend = FALSE` within `geom_point`. Here is an example using ggplot2's diamonds dataset.

```
s <- diamonds
p <- ggplot(data = s, aes(x = depth, y = price))
p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cut)), show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image: plot with no legend]

Comment: It says: Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: show.legend

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

```
p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(clustering)),show.legend=FALSE)
```

Comment: It says: Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: show.legend

Comment: Yes,it's right.  Show.legend is a geom_point parameter. Check up,please, the correct number of closing parenthesis before show.legend parameter.